# PySpark - Create DataFrame from Numpy Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a numpy matrix:

```
arr = np.array([[2,3], [2,8], [2,3],[4,5]])
```

I need to create a PySpark Dataframe from `arr`. I can not manually input the values because the length/values of `arr` will be changing dynamically so I need to convert `arr` into a dataframe.

I tried the following code to no success.

```
df= sqlContext.createDataFrame(arr,["A", "B"])
```

However, I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

#sample data
arr = np.array([[2,3], [2,8], [2,3],[4,5]])

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(arr)
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x])
df = rdd2.toDF(["A", "B"])
df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  2|  3|
|  2|  8|
|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to use the RDD API. Simply:

```
mat = np.random.random((10,3))
cols = ["ColA","ColB","ColC"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(mat.tolist(), cols)
df.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
arr = np.array([[2,3], [2,8], [2,3],[4,5]])
df = np.concatenate(arr).reshape(1000,-1)
dff = map(lambda x: (int(x[0]), Vectors.dense(x[1:])), df)
mydf = spark.createDataFrame(dff,schema=["label", "features"])
mydf.show(5)
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (1000,newaxis)` on line 4