# Convert matrix to Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I've a matrix which is 1000*10000 size. I want to convert this matrix into pyspark dataframe.

Can someone please tell me how to do it? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206622/pyspark-create-dataframe-from-numpy-matrix) has an example. But my number of columns is large. So, assigning column names manually will be difficult.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a Pyspark Dataframe, you can use the function [createDataFrame()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame)

```
matrix=([11,12,13,14,15],[21,22,23,24,25],[31,32,33,34,35],[41,42,43,44,45])

df=spark.createDataFrame(matrix)

df.show()

>
+---+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4| _5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15|
| 21| 22| 23| 24| 25|
| 31| 32| 33| 34| 35|
| 41| 42| 43| 44| 45|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

As you can see above, the columns will be named automatically with numbers.
You can also pass your own column names to the `createDataFrame()` function:

```
columns=[ 'mycol_'+str(col) for col in range(5) ]

df=spark.createDataFrame(matrix,schema=columns)

df.show()
>
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|mycol_0|mycol_1|mycol_2|mycol_3|mycol_4|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     11|     12|     13|     14|     15|
|     21|     22|     23|     24|     25|
|     31|     32|     33|     34|     35|
|     41|     42|     43|     44|     45|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I'm getting the error `rowmatrix` is not iterable.